# Can you exchange Armenian currency for Euros in Paris CDG airport?

Tags: exchange, cdg

I am traveling to Paris in November from the USA, and I still have some Armenian currency from another recent trip that I did not exchange before returning home.  I saw that there are direct flights from Yerevan, Armenia to France. Do you know if I can exchange Armenian currency for Euros in Paris?

Answer (score 11):

If you're asking specifically about the CDG airport in Paris, the answer seems to be **no, you can't**.

[Travelex](http://www.parisaeroport.fr/en/passengers/services/money-mails-health/money-bank/exchange) operates the exchange services at CDG and their currency page says they [generally buy the currencies](https://www.travelex.fr/autres-services/revendre-devises-etrangeres) they sell and [Armenian AMD](https://acheter.travelex.fr/fr/Basket) isn't listed there.

If you're looking to convert them in Paris proper, places that take AMD are surprisingly hard to find, but I did find at least one, [Comptoir des Tuileries](https://www.cdt.fr/devises/exotiques/prix.html) (53, rue Vivienne), that buys AMD.